# Customizar o Chekbox do Contact Form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, formulário, checkbox

Estou tentando customizar um checkbox do contact form 7, wordpress, mas não estou tendo resultado!
Ele deveria ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E ele está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código no contact form é esse:

```
<label2 style="width:99%">Disciplina<br>[checkbox* disciplina class:disciplinaform "Biologia" "Física" "Matemática" "Química"]</label2>
```

Esse é o código que peguei pelo navegador dessa área:

```
<label2 style="margin-top: 26px; margin-bottom:20px; display:inline-block">Disciplina<br><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap disciplina"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox disciplina" id="disciplina"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first"><input type="checkbox" name="disciplina[]" value="Biologia"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Biologia</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="disciplina[]" value="Física"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Física</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="disciplina[]" value="Matemática"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Matemática</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item last"><input type="checkbox" name="disciplina[]" value="Química"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Química</span></span></span></span></label2>
```

Não sei se ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Se existe um CSS para o checkbox mas não está funcionando talvez falte zerar a aparência deles:

```
.disciplina > input[type="checkbox"] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
```

Após é só definir um background normal e no state checked. Por exemplo:

```
.disciplina > input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
       background: blue;
    }
```

E no label2 (achei estranha essa tag, não deveria ser somente label?) se acrescentar "display: inline-block" deve "desgrudar" da select acima dele.

Editando: 
Você pode utilizar o span logo após o checkbox que está com a class wpcf7-list-item-label fazendo o pseudo elemento :after

```
.wpcf7-list-item-label:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px; //dimensão maior que a padrão que quiser
    height: 26px;
    background: grey;
}
```

Vai ter ainda que criar a situação :checked, exemplo:

```
input:checked + .wpcf7-list-item-label:after {
    background: blue;
  }
```

Comment: A dica do inline-block funcionou, eles agora estão na mesma linha. Mas ainda não consegui estilizar o campo checkbox, para que o quadradinho fique como na imagem, maior e com background cinza.

Comment: Eu acrescentei uma possibilidade, mas o appearance tirou os padrões do checkbox?